# Open stream from FFmpeg on VLC media player

Tags: linux, windows, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, streaming

I'm using the following command to start a video stream on a Linux/Ubuntu machine:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -r 25 -s 800x600 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec libx264 -preset fast -tune zerolatency -b 900k -f mpegts udp://10.0.0.8:1234
```

How do I view this stream from VLC player on my Windows machine?
I tried the following but VLC just opens without any error message but displays nothing:

```
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" rtp://@:1234
```

The Windows machines address is `10.0.0.8`.

The Linux machines address is `10.0.0.41`.

Comment: Have you tried using `udp://` on the VLC side instead of `rtp://`?

Comment: @heavyd Yea, has the same result.

Comment: @Nathan have you resolved the problem?

Comment: @peetonn I have not